# How to find which build paths a project is on

Tags: java, eclipse, build, classpath, buildpath

Suppose I have a Java project in Eclipse called `ProjectA`. I have 50 other projects and I want a list of projects that have `ProjectA` as part of their build path.

How do I get such a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is - from Eclipse menu > Search > File, do a search as per this screen

[image]

Or if you use Maven, do a search for 'ProjectA' in all pom.xml